# How to efficiently use fetched objects from background thread in main thread?

Tags: swift, core-data

I need to use `NSManagedObjects` instances in my UI. I understand that after fetching in background thread, in contrast to the objects themselves,  `NSManagedObjectID`  can be safely passed to main thread and then used in **`existingObject(with:)`**  method to retrieve the objects for use in UI. However, I'm not clear on the efficiency of this approach, particularly calling  **`existingObject(with:)`**  in main thread for each object.

Like in the following example:

```
let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
let mainContext = persistentContainer.viewContext

backgroundContext.perform {
    do {
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<MyEntity> = MyEntity.fetchRequest()
        let fetchedObjects = try backgroundContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        
        let objectIDs = fetchedObjects.map { $0.objectID }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let mainThreadObjects = objectIDs.map { mainContext.object(with: $0) as! MyEntity }
        }
    } catch {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Is **`existingObject(with:)`** just a quicker version of a fetch request, or is it essentially an instant operation? I mean while we fetch objects on a background thread to avoid blocking the main thread, we still end up using **`existingObject(with:)`** on the main thread for each object. Wouldn't this risk blocking the main thread as well (worsening UX) especially if there are many objects?

Would it be more efficient to convert the fetched objects in background into structs and then pass them safely to the main thread? but in this case wouldn't I have to fetch object each time I want to modify it? I surfed internet but couldn't find proper explanation.

I appreciate any insights on this. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see the point of using a background context if all you do is fetch the objects and then pass them on directly to the main thread. Then you might as well fetch them directly using your main context. Another option when only fetching  though is to use NSAsynchronousFetchRequest so you might want to look into that.

Comment: the thing is that if I fetch in main thread In worst case scenario app fetches around 300-400 objects during some animation and it causes a slight glitch, I thought to move this fetching process to background to avoid that. with NSAsynchronousFetchRequest can I fetch objects in background and use these objects in main thread (modify them as well)?

Comment: Why not research what NSAsynchronousFetchRequest is and see if it might be useful.

Comment: well I see I cant directly use  fetched objects by  NSAsynchronousFetchRequest in main thread

Comment: four HUNDRED objects ??

Comment: I consider worst case scenario :) they are very lightweight btw

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making this harder than it needs to be. In general, you shouldn't pass specific managed object instances into SwiftUI. You should instead pass a managed object context into SwiftUI, then use the [FetchRequest property wrapper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/fetchrequest) to fetch objects. A fetch request can have a predicate, but if you're trying to fetch all instances of MyEntity in the managed object context, you can leave that off.

As objects are added to or removed from the managed object context, your UI will update automatically. For example, if you are working with an API which provides access to remote objects living on some server, you can download the data and import it to managed objects in a background thread, save the managed object context, and the objects will just appear in your UI.

Comment: the code I provided is just an example, I use the fetched objects in different views and store them in shared view model